# Code that creates matrix with random 0 and 1 values

Tags: javascript, matrix, random

Can you please write a js code that fills empty matrix randomly with 0 or 1? I need to use Random() function.

I wrote this code and I got an error Random() is not defined

```
var matrix = [];


for(var y = 0; y<5; y++){
    for(var x = 0; x<5; x++){
        let arr = [0,1]
     matrix[y][x]= random(arr)
      matrix.push(matrix[y][x])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `Math.random()` and then use `Math.round()` to get `0` or `1`.
Secondly you should set `matrix[y]` to an empty array otherwise code will throw error.

```js
var matrix = [];

for(var y = 0; y<5; y++){
    matrix[y] = [];
    for(var x = 0; x<5; x++){
      matrix[y][x]= Math.round(Math.random())
      matrix.push(matrix[y][x])
    }
}
console.log(matrix)
```

An easier to create a matrix of any length you can use `map()`. Create an array of given length and map it to a another array with same length have random values from `0` or `1`

```js
const getMatrix = len => [...Array(len)].map(x => [...Array(len)].map(b => Math.round(Math.random())));

let res = getMatrix(5);
console.log(res)
```

For different length and width use two parameters.

```js
const getMatrix = (l,w) => [...Array(l)].map(x => [...Array(w)].map(b => Math.round(Math.random())));

let res = getMatrix(2,3);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Math.round(Math.random())`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it using ES6:

```js
const arr = new Array(5).fill().map(() => new Array(5).fill().map(() => Math.round(Math.random())));

console.log(arr);
```

You have to use the `fill()` method before `map()`, otherwise you will get undefined values.

The "classical" way to do it using your snippet of code will be similar to what you tried, with the addition of the standard built-in object `Math` which has the `random()` method and also `round()` to get integer values. If you want a matrix (2D array) then you will need to push an array into each row, otherwise you will get a simple array.

```js
var matrix = [];

for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    const row = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      row.push(Math.round(Math.random()));
    }
    matrix.push(row);
}

console.log(matrix);
```